# Redirect is not working when inside a method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to put the redirect inside of a method, it won't redirect, but if I put the redirect directly, it will redirect. Please see my code below.

**Checking method** – *This method will redirect when session is null*

```
private function loadIdChecker()
{
    if(session('load_id') === null) {
        return redirect()->route('load-calculator');
    }
}
```

**Users view method (NOT WORKING)**

```
public function users()
{
  $this->loadIdChecker();

  ... The rest of the code here
}
```

**Users view method (WORKING)**

```
public function users()
{
  if(session('load_id') === null) {
    return redirect()->route('load-calculator');
  }
}
```

Comment: try: `return $this->loadIdChecker();` instead of just: `$this->loadIdChecker();` in your users() functions

Comment: @illusion I cannot use `return` in users method since I still have other code below

Comment: @Jonjie Then you will have to include your code into the users method as you did in your last example.

Comment: @Aless55 So, the behavior of my code is normal?

Comment: Yes, the redirect only happens if you return it at the top level which is your users methodi If you only call the function, the returned value (in this case the redirect) will simply not be used at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirects only work properly when you give the redirect instance to the response handler of Laravel. Right now, it just returns back an instance of `Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse`. So, ***if*** for some reason, you don't wish to change the method body of load checker, you could just add an additional change as to returning `true` or whatever at the end to judge the difference in the response as below:

```
private function loadIdChecker(){
    if(session('load_id') === null) {
        return redirect()->route('load-calculator');
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then, in your code, you could check like below:

```
public function users()
{
  $returned_val = $this->loadIdChecker();
  if($returned_val instanceof Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse){
     return $returned_val;
  }

  // The rest of the code goes here
}
```

---

The best way to tackle this is to have a middleware that checks for `load_id` and redirects to the `load-calculator` page if `load_id` is null. Handling redirection via a method is not recommended, especially if it's some kind of auth check.

Comment: Will take the `middleware` way to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

Try: `return $this->loadIdChecker();` instead of just `$this->loadIdChecker();` in your `users()` function.

The bug occurs because in your original code the `users` function is not returning anything while it is expected to return something...

Comment: I cannot use `return` in users method since I still have other code below

Comment: returning the redirect() is essential for your code to work. In your case, since you have other code that needs to be run, you can create an if block, which returns the redirect. BUT RETURNING THE REDIRECT IS ESSENTIAL. That's why your second piece of code is working, because of the return statement

Comment: now, you can have to ways to go about it. First, is the second piece of code that works, simple and up to point. Otherwise, you can return a boolean from `loadIdChecker()` check its value in `users()`. if it is false, then return redirect, else continue with your remaining code

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add a return statement (and maybe also take into account a case where load_id !== null).

```
public function users()
{
  return $this->loadIdChecker();
}
```

Comment: I cannot use `return` in users method since I still have other code below

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
Public function index()
{
   echo  this->checksession();

   "Your other code"

}

public function checksession()
{
   if(Session::get('your_id')== '') 
    {
       return redirect('Yoururl')->with('msg','your message')
    } 
   
}
```

logic is just remove return and add echo it will show a redirect link but it works